# jquery json facebook wall

Tags: jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

i try to follow this tutorial (http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/custom-facebook-wall-jquery-graph/) but when i put my ID and ACCESS_TOKEN nothing happend, doesnt show the wall. Look, http://recorramisiones.com.ar/rutadelaselva/fbwall/. My ID an ACCESS_TOKEN works because the script show the facebook page title (RUTA DE LA SELVA). All the code is in the page tutorial. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't show your app access token in the source code. Anybody can steal it from there...

You can combine to two requests into one like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/larutadelaselvamisioneraguarani/?fields=name,picture,posts&access_token={access_token}
```

and you will receive a valid response. So if "nothing is shown", the problem is in your surrounding JS code.